# Haskell Error Handler

Tags: haskell

I'm making a feeble attempt at writing a error handler in Haskell. My Haskell skills are quite abysmal. Can some knowledgable person tell me how to correct this evaluation?

```
data Checked a = Good a | Error String

evaluate :: Exp -> Env -> Checked Value
evaluate (Call fun arg) env =
  case evaluate fun env of
    Error msg -> Error (msg ++ "Error")
    Good func ->
      case evaluate arg env of
        Error msg -> Error (msg ++ "error")
        Good arg0 -> 
          let ClosureV x body env' = av
            evaluate body ((x, arg0) : env')
```

I know it needs to return a Checked Value, but not sure how to write that in.

Comment: Well, not knowing all of the details, it looks like your function type check, "eventually". You just need to define a base case at some point and return either a "Good Value" or "Error String". Also, you might want to try using the Either monad to clarify your code a bit, for example: http://lpaste.net/252351829973663744 With that said, it is a bit hard to know exactly what you are asking here.

Comment: What is `av`? What is `ClosureV`? What's the purpose of `++ "Error"` and `++ "error"`; are you trying to add a trace to the site of the error in the error message?

Answer (score 1):

You have almost made your first monad.

Let's look at the body of `evaluate (Call fun arg) env`.

```
evaluate (Call fun arg) env =
  case evaluate fun env of
    Error msg -> Error msg
    Good func ->
      case evaluate arg env of
        Error msg -> Error msg
        Good arg0 ->
          ...
```

There's a pattern here. If we laid the two `case`s over the top of each other it would look like the following, where the first mess of `███` comes from typing the word `arg` over the top of `fun` and the second mess comes from typing the word `arg0` over the top of `func`

```
case evaluate ███ env of
  Error msg -> Error msg
  Good ████ ->
    ...
```

In both cases, we are examining some `Checked a`. We are passing into the case expression some `Checked` value and doing something else, that also results in some checked value, if the checked value is `Good`. Let's ignore everything from the `evaluate` part

```
case ███ of
  Error msg -> Error msg
  Good ████ ->
    ...
```

We are using this pattern repeatedly, so let's extract it.

```
whenGood :: Checked a -> (a -> Checked b) -> Checked b
whenGood checked next = case checked of
                            Error msg -> Error msg
                            Good  x   -> next  x
```

Now we can write `evaluate (Call fun arg) env` equivalently as

```
evaluate (Call fun arg) env =
    whenGood (evaluate fun env) $ \func ->
      whenGood (evaulate arg env) $ \arg0 ->
        ...
```

We don't need the indentation (lambdas extend as far right as possible), and can write `whenGood` as an infix operator. This looks very nice.

```
evaluate (Call fun arg) env =
    evaluate fun env `whenGood` \func ->
    evaluate arg env `whenGood` \arg0 ->
    ...
```

The type of whenGood matches the type of `>>=` for a `Monad`.

```
whenGood ::            Checked a -> (a -> Checked b) -> Checked b
(>>=)    :: Monad m => m       a -> (a -> m       b) -> m       b
```

To define a `Monad` we also need a `return` with the type `a -> m a`. Your `Good` constructor puts a value `a` into a `Checked a`.

```
return :: Monad m => a -> m       a
Good   ::            a -> Checked a
```

I'll assert that `whenGood` and `Good` obey the [`Monad` laws](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:Monad) for `(>>=)` and `return`, so we can make a `Monad` instance for `Checked`<sup>†</sup>

```
instance Monad Checked where
    return = Good
    (>>=)  = whenGood
```

Having a `Monad` instance means that we can use any of the [functions defined in general for `Monad`s](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html). It also lets us write our `evaluate (Call fun arg) env` with the more familiar `>>=` operator in place of `whenGood`.

```
evaluate (Call fun arg) env =
    evaluate fun env >>= \func ->
    evaluate arg env >>= \arg0 ->
    ...
```

Or even in `do` notation

```
evaluate (Call fun arg) env =
  do
    func <- evaluate fun env
    arg0 <- evaluate arg env
    ...
```

---

<sup>†</sup>If you have a newer GHC it might complain that `Monad`s need an `Applicative` instance, if so you can make the default one.

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad

instance Functor Checked where
    fmap = liftM

instance Applicative Checked where
    pure  = return
    (<*>) = ap
```